# Local umbraco site permissions issue

Tags: permissions, localhost, umbraco, local

I'm certain I'm having a permissions with my local umbraco site. my site is located in my wwwroot folder, I've set up my hosts file with the following entry: '127.0.0.1    dev.umbraco-site.com'.

The IIS sites physical path is set too the folder which contains the web.config file, my application pool is v4.0 Integrated.

I've gone through and ensured that my wwwroot and root folder for the site both have full control as far as permissions go for all users, But I'm just getting a 'HTTP ERROR 500' on my browser.

What am I missing? Is there anything else I should check? I'm sure it's a permissions issue but I can't think of where else I need to look. I've read this documentation, especially around the 'Server setup' as there is permissions referenced there: https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/ but it didn't help so it makes me wander if the issue is on an IIS level?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you debugging through VS with IIS Express or trying to run it fully with IIS on your local machine?

Comment: I'm trying to run it fully with IIS on my local machine. If I try running it with IIS Express I get the the following error 'HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working after installing an IIS re-direct extension which resolved the issue.